# Multiple words as a possible variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, multiple-conditions

The line **Hi=("Hi" "Hello" "Hey")** has the possible inputs. I've tried adding a comma between the words and that does not work either. If *hi*, *hello*, or *hey* are typed in, I need it to echo "Hi". Right now only *Hi* works. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to make "synonyms" for a word. The ability to substitute a one word for another.

```
    clear; echo
    shopt -s nocasematch
    echo; read -p "    > " TextInput

    Hi=("Hi" "Hello" "Hey")

     if [[ "$TextInput" == $Hi ]]; then
    clear; echo; echo
    echo -e "    >> Hi"
    echo

     else
    clear; echo; echo
    echo -e "    >> Error"
    echo
    fi
```

I know I could use

```
     if [[ "$TextInput" == "Hi" ]] || [[ "$TextInput" == "Hello" ]] || [[ "$TextInput" == "Hey" ]]; then
```

but that will get to be way too long.

Comment: `bash` arrays don't work well for this kind of set operation because they were developed as a type of second-level quoting, not as a container type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your target is bash 4.0 or newer, an associative array will work:

```
TextInput=Hello
declare -A values=( [Hi]=1 [Hello]=1 [Hey]=1 )

if [[ ${values[$TextInput]} ]]; then
  echo "Hi there!"
else
  echo "No Hi!"
fi
```

This is an O(1) lookup, making it faster than an O(n) loop-based traversal.

---

That said, if the list of items you're matching against is hardcoded, just use a case statement:

```
case $TextInput in
  Hi|Hello|Hey) echo "Hi there!" ;;
  *)            echo "No Hi!     ;;
esac
```

This also has the advantage of being compatible with any shell compliant with POSIX sh.

Comment: Thank you! If I added an *elif* is there a way to use the same "Hi" options with it?

    `elif [[ "$TextInput" == "Hi, how are you" ]]; then`
    `echo "Good"`

Comment: @Seaner992, I'm not sure what you mean by the question. `[[ ]]` behaves the same way whether or not it's in the `then` part of an if statement, an elif, or not in an `if` at all. I don't see anywhere in your original question where there's a path leading to "Good".

Comment: Please don't use pastebin.com -- it's full of ads for anyone not running Adblock. http://gist.github.com/ is much friendlier.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aee1c2d3302f270829db

I was hoping to use your answer to use it on other if statements, that way Hi/Hey/Hello didn't have to be typed in a bunch.

Comment: ...so, `declare -A responses=( ["Hi how are you"]=1 ["Hey how are you"]=1 )`, and `[[ ${responses[$TextInput]} ]]` to check.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this variant:

```
TextInput="Hello"
Hi=("Hi" "Hello" "Hey")

flag=0

for myhi in ${Hi[@]}; do
    if [[ "$TextInput" == "$myhi" ]]; then
        flag=1
        break
    fi
done

if [[ $flag == 1 ]]; then
    echo "Hi there!"
else
    echo "No Hi!"
fi
```

The thing is: use a flag + a for loop. If the flag is set (=1), then the `TextInput` is equal to something in your `Hi` array.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can also use a switch:

```
case "$input" in
  "Hi"|"He"*)
    echo Hello
    ;;
  *)
    echo Error
    ;;
  esac
```

This allows you to also specify patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash's pattern matching:

```
$ Hi=(Hi Hello Hey)
$ input=foo
$ if (IFS=:; [[ ":${Hi[*]}:" == *:"$input":* ]]); then echo Y; else echo N; fi
N
$ input=Hey
$ if (IFS=:; [[ ":${Hi[*]}:" == *:"$input":* ]]); then echo Y; else echo N; fi
Y
```

I use parentheses here to spawn a subshell, so changes to the IFS variable don't affect the current shell.